# Does each particle along mechanical transverse wave achieve the same maximum vertical displacement?

Tags: waves

The maximum vertical displacement of transverse wave is called amplitude. As the wave propagates to X-direction, the particles vibrate vertically. Does each particle that vibrates vertically achieve the same amplitude?

Answer (score 0):

If the medium has a constant density then yes each particle will reach the same amplitude.

The way to think about this is that the wave is transferring energy through the medium - as the particles oscillate they gain potential energy as they approach the maximum and then loose it again.

If the medium had a varying composition (density, pressure or something else) then the particles would not need to reach the same amplitude to gain the same potential energy.

I think a better way to answer your question is that the particles all reach the same potential energy - if the medium is uniform then this is the same as reaching the same amplitude.

Comment: Thanks. If a string is connected to source of vibration (SHM) at one end, and fixed/free end boundary at another end, do the SHM and the travelling wave have the same frequencies?

Comment: @DavidHM Yes. Since the SHM source is providing the oscillation it must necessarily have the same period, and hence frequency, as the wave it produces

Comment: Thanks. My textbook doesn't mention it

Answer (score 0):

If a wave is spreading in two or three dimensions, then its amplitude will decrease with distance.  Any frictional interactions could also cause a loss of energy.

Comment: I mean during constant vibration of the source and the medium has boundary